Switching Tenure-Track Positions Within Same University
Is it common or possible to apply for internal faculty position at the same university? I am assistant professor at a University's department-A and considering applying to a similar position in a different faculty/department-B within same university as the new role provides way better resources (Department B has recently advertised a position online).

Is it common to apply for internal positions at the same university?
Any advice on navigating this while maintaining good relationships in
both departments?


Is a joint appointment a possibility?

Changing from Biology to Biochemistry in the School of Arts and Sciences might well be different from changing from Physics (in Arts and Sciences) to Electrical Engineering in the School of Engineering.

@JonCuster I haven't explored the joint appointment idea yet. However, it might be difficult since Faculty B is heavily funding the new position and likely wants more control over teaching and research duties. Although the departments are in separate faculties, their interests are similar, and faculty often collaborate and teach in both. Your example of Biology to Biochemistry is apt. Another example is Environmental Health Sciences (Public Health) and Earth and Environmental Sciences (Arts and Sciences) at Columbia University.

@Trunk No, Department B has not hopped a ball and entirely my idea. No such recent case exist AFAIK.

It should be possible. I've no idea how common it is.
As for the second question - I would not do this without the blessing of colleagues in the department you're now in and encouragement from people in the department you want to join. Anything less risks hard feelings whether the application succeeds or fails.

Do you need someone’s blessing to break up with them, really? Do you need an employer’s blessing to quit? That’s absurd. Of course OP would need the blessing of the department they want to join, but as for the colleagues in the current department, their opinion may count for something but certainly should not be a determining factor in OP’s decision.

@DanRomik Not absurd. For example, at UCSD, the FTE goes with the transfer, so the losing department has to be willing to give it up. As you can see, the endorsement of the losing department chair is necessary.

@user71659 interesting, I stand corrected. And thanks for the link, that’s a very useful document that sheds additional light into these sorts of situations.

Context: United States. I'm not sure how applicable what I wrote is to other countries.
Moving departments within the same institution is not common, but should usually be possible through an administrative process that is a lot less cumbersome and competitive than getting a position at the institution in the first place. At my institution where I have seen this happen, the main hurdle that needs to be cleared is that the faculty of department B have to take a vote and confirm that they approve of the faculty member from department A joining their department. Then there is an approval process where various deans and committees have to sign off on the move, but if the faculty of department B are happy with it I think that's basically the end of the story and no one else is likely to object.
For this reason, if you are interested in moving from department A to department B at the same university, I would think that the correct process to follow is to start by exploring the idea informally with department B's department chair, and/or other colleagues at that department who you think may be supportive of your move. Most likely you will either find that department B is not really open to that idea (e.g., maybe they think your research profile is a poor fit for them), or instead you will find that they are indeed open to the idea and would be willing to get the ball rolling on the relevant administrative process.
In any case, I'd bet that you would not be required at any point to apply to an advertised tenure track position the way outside candidates need to do. And I'm also reasonably sure that if you do just decide to apply to such a position on your own initiative using the regular application process, you will be informed that this is not a correct or practical way to approach the department switch idea.

Any advice on navigating this while maintaining good relationships in both departments?

If you approach department B politely and respectfully with your request, I don't see why this would hurt your relationship with anyone there. (If anything, they should be flattered that you want to join them.) Possibly they will tell you no, which could be a bit awkward, but that does not seem like a huge problem to worry about.
On the other hand, I can see that under some circumstances your colleagues in department A may take offense to your wanting to leave their department, especially if you are someone they worked hard to recruit and/or whose presence is strategically important to them. So there is a chance this might sour your relationship with some of them. This could potentially be quite awkward, especially if your gambit to move to department B fails. But again, if you approach the various conversations with tact and respect and offer good explanations of why you are trying to move, hopefully your department A colleagues would understand and you will avoid upsetting them too much. But in the end, even with the best of intentions it may be impossible to avoid some damage to your relationships with them.
Good luck!

It is possible.  In the new position you may have to start over from scratch on seniority---negotiate this with the new department.

Or it could be the opposite. For example, any transfer within the University of California (even across campuses) retains seniority and tenure timelines do not reset.

^ That could be a double edged sword as you may need time to reestablish your research program in the new field in a limited time.
